# Simple HTML5 Platformer Tutorials Written Entirely in Core JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I've been searching the net for HTML5 platformer tutorials that fulfill the following criteria:

1. Written entirely in core JavaScript using just HTML5 APIs (e.g. Canvas)
2. No usage of third party game libraries or engines (whether paid or free)
3. Use of popular, non-game libraries like jQuery is ok
4. Can run on iOS and Android devices

Don't know if that's a tall order? I found a couple of "Breakout" tutorials that fulfill the criteria above, but no solid platformers so far (there ARE platformers out there that may fulfill the criteria, but not in tutorial form)

If you could provide a list of URLs would be great.

Thanks very much in advance :-)

Comment: Sorry, thought for a sec you wanted examples (See http://www.beautyoftheweb.com/#/experience/pixellab for good examples)

Comment: so you want a platform that does not rely on any other library?

Comment: i think by "platformer" he's referring to a special game genre. Platformers are generally 2d Jump 'n runs.

Comment: I mean Platformer = platform game :-)